# How can implement this code in a Polymer Element (Polymer 2.0)

Tags: javascript, animation, polymer, polymer-2.x

Currently I am trying to put this JavaScript code in my Polymer element however, it always fails due to the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null".

JavaScript code:

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

var appHeader = document.querySelector('app-header');
var bgHeader = document.querySelector('.bg-header');
var appHeaderHeight = appHeader.offsetHeight;
var bgHeaderHeight = bgHeader.offsetHeight;

var transformBgHeader = function() {
var y = window.scrollY;
if (y <= bgHeaderHeight) {
  y = 1.5 * y;
}
var s = bgHeader.style;
s.transform = s.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,' + -y + 'px,0)';
appHeader.shadow = y > bgHeaderHeight - appHeaderHeight;
}

transformBgHeader();

addEventListener('scroll', transformBgHeader);

});
```

P.S: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give an id to the elements matching selectors, app-header and .bg-header. Assuming #appHeader and #bgHeader. And, access the attribute offsetHeight like this.

```
this.$.appHeader.offsetHeight
this.$.bgHeader.offsetHeight
```

> Class-based elements should use the native DOM APIs instead of the
>   Polymer.dom APIs. Legacy elements can optionally use the native APIs.

Ref. https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#polymer-dom-apis